# Laravel change request value

Tags: laravel, request

I'm using laravel 8 and I want to change the 'courierStatus' value in the requests to 10.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
 $request->courierStatus = 10;

 log::debug($request);
}
```

result is

```
local.INFO: array (
  'courierStatus' => NULL,
)
```

But when I inserted the value to DB, 10 is inserted . So if the variable has value, Why the log is showing null ?

Comment: How did you insert the value to DB? Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $request['courierStatus'] = 10;
```

Comment: yes. this also correct. but i want to know what is the reason for that.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 